# C# Getting the sum of nested values of a nested dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda, nested-loops

I have a dictionary that has the follow structure:

```
{
    "group_1": {
        "a": 1.0,
        "b": 1.5,
        "c": 2.0,
        "d": 4.0
    },
    "group_2": {
        "a": 3.0,
        "b": 3.5,
        "c": 6.0,
        "d": 4.7
    },
    "group_3": {
        "a": 0,
        "b": 1.9,
        "c": 2.1,
        "d": 3.0
    },
    "group_4": {
        "a": 0.4,
        "b": 1.3,
        "c": 1.0,
        "d": 2.0
    }
}
```

What I was trying to do is to sum all the corresponding values of all of sibling dicts and create a new dict as follows:

```
{
    "a": 3.4,
    "b": 7.2,
    "c": 11.1,
    "d": 13.7
}
```

I would like to use a more succinct and elegant way, and it needs to be dynamic, because I can't know for sure how many group dictionaries or how much letters it will have.

I've tried the foreach approach, but I can't really understand how to get only positional value of each dictionary in each loop.

```
var formatedDataList = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> group in fortmatedData)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> alternative in group.Value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
var formatedDataList = fortmatedData
    .SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value) // Flatten nested dictionaries
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.
Just had to convert the kvp.Value to double, since its beeing received as a string. 
Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over internal dictionaries and add a key if it doesn't exist:

```
dict.Aggregate(new Dictionary<string, double>(), (x, y) => {
    foreach (var kvp in y.Value) {
        x[kvp.Key] = (x.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out var sum) ? sum : 0) + kvp.Value;
    }
    return x;
});
```

This solution has 3x smaller complexity than the solution with grouping. Can be used for larger datasets.

Comment: Nice solution, although the complexity is not x3 smaller. `SelectMany` + `GroupBy` has a combined complexity of `n` rather than `2n`, and `ToDictionary` has a complexity of `m`, where `m` is the number of groups returned from `GroupBy`. The difference in complexity is actually `n` vs `n + m`.

Comment: Great solution.
But, since I'm not expecting that larger dataset yet, I can stick to a better readability. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I didn't actually check the complexity of separate operations, just compared the performance of both and this is 3x faster which seems to be linear in the function of m, but you're probably right